# find 2nd highest value in array during loop in asp (classic) with Java

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, asp-classic

In a ASP Classic script I have a loop. In each recordset there is an array called "portos" (7, 4, 12) where I need to forward the highest and 2nd highest value.

For now I get the max value and pass it on to a link with this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var v=[<%=portos %>]
   var porto=parseInt((Math.max.apply(0,v)), 10);
   document.links["link"].href += porto;
   </script>
   <a id="link" href="somepage.asp?maxv=">Link</a>
```

Unfortunately it only works outside of the loop. Inside I get all the numbers in the first recordset and none in the others. This is one problem. The other is in the title: how do I get the second highest value into the link?

I'm a total noob to Java and thinking around this since days... Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to sort the array from highest to lowest, then grab the first two members:

```
// Array might be numbers or strings or a bit of both
var x = ['123', '14', 7, 4, '12', -3];

// Sort numbers from higest to lowest
function sortNumReversed(a, b) {

  // Ensure a and b are numbers, lots of ways to do this
  a = Number(a), b = Number(b);

  // Return result of comparison
  return b == a ? 0 : b < a? -1 : 1;
}

x.sort(sortNumReversed);

alert('Highest: ' + x[0] + '\nSecond highest: ' + x[1]);
```

Comment: +1 and a simpler sort function is `function(a,b){return Number(b)-Number(a)}`.

Comment: @RobG - Thank's a lot! It does not work for me inside the loop but I can use it another way. Works like a charm!

Comment: @maerics - Yes, looks way nicer ;) But since I have nearly no idea I like the comments on top of every line.