# "NaN" Error in IE from submitted value in asp classic

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asp-classic, nan

I have a little Script that refreshes a page within a div tag. There is a value (max number from a array) sent with the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshmydiv() {
var v=[<%=portos %>]
var porto=parseInt((Math.max.apply(0,v)), 10)
        new Ajax.Request('shop/wk.asp?varp=' + porto, {
            method: 'post' ,
            onSuccess: function(request) {
                $('Container').update(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Firefox opens the file wk.asp without any problems and does with the value what it should. ...formatting, calculating, whatever... For example:

```
<% porto = int(request.querystring("varp")) %>
<%= Formatnumber(porto,2,0,0,-1)%>
```

Internet Explorer gives me an "NaN" Error as soon as I try to do something numerical with it.

Any way to transmit this number that IE also plays along?

Comment: What's the output from `<%=portos %>`?

Comment: it something like "4, 12, 7". with "porto" I get the "12"

Comment: The only thing I can think of is IE having some problem with `Math.max.apply(0,arr)`. Or if your array contains a non-numerical value, then `Math.max` returns `NaN`.

Comment: You really better find the max number in the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you bfavaretto!
IE doesn't like the Math.max.apply(0,arr) to use as numerical value later on.
To find the highest number in the array I used the solution by RobG from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697693/find-2nd-highest-value-in-array-during-loop-in-asp-classic-with-java). Thanx to him again. NaN solved :)